# Product image not zooming in properly when hovering on image at product detail page

Tags: product, magento-2.1, product-images, zoom

In my product page detail when i try to hover the product image there's only white box with low opacity overlaying at the top of my image like this :

[image]

Usually in Magento 2, when hovering the image it will zoom in the part where the image is hovered like this:

[image]

I've tried to edit view.xml in my app/design/frontend/theme, but i can't get it to work, here's the code:

```
<var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>
```

Comment: Image size should be large. Please check first image size.

Comment: @SHPatel my image size is 1200x1200

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Check the css for class "magnifier-preview" in firebug. The 'left' could be out of page. If you reduce the left margin you will see the zoom is working. However I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: do you use a custom theme? Did you make any changes to layout, template or css/js?

Comment: How to add this file in custom module ?

Answer (score 0):

Change below var :

```
<var name="width">1200</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
<var name="height">1200</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I get the solution, please change code as given below this code working for me.

```
<var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top">0</var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left">100%</var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width">250</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height">250</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It was a CSS issue for mine. Please add this line to any CSS file.**

```
.magnifier-preview img { max-height:inherit; }
```